# Problem when connecting my device to PC?

Tags: android, windows-xp

I can't connect my device `Samsung Galaxy SII` to my pc. I'm using Windwos XP 32-bit Operating System. I've also installed Samsung Kies. And, in eclipse i've also change the run configurations to `Manual` also. Why it's not connected. Anyone help me to connect that please? Advance Thanks.

Comment: Connect means you just want to detect device via USB or want to start with application development?

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani : Want to develop the application.

Comment: Is there any kind of warning or message given either by the PC or mobile...?

Comment: @SamSPICA : No such warnings i'd not. What to do?

Comment: restart your computer. have usb settings to "Charge Only".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes exactly now as you want to start with android application development on your real device samsung galaxy SII, just go through this checkout steps:

1. **settings->Applications->Unknown sources**
2. **Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging**

These 2 steps are necessary before starting development with real device.

Answer (score 4):

get the device "Hardware Ids" from the device manager and add them to the android_winusb.inf file in "...\android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver" like

> ; HTC Desire HD
>
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CA2&MI_01
>
> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CA2&REV_0226&MI_01

these are the values for htc desire hd,

UPDATE: the values for the galaxy sII are

> ; Samsung Galaxy S II
>
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_685E&MI_03
>
> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_685E&REV_0400&MI_03

Answer (score 0):

Un-check the USB debugging mode (from Settings - Development; if it's checked), and try to reconnect. Also, check that the Settings - Connect to PC is not set as default to "Charge Only", make sure to connect it as "Mass Storage" / "Disk Drive" initially.