# how to run android apps in devices

Tags: android, adb

I installed the driver for Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet in my PC (Windows7), but i can't get device-name when I run `adb device` command in cmd prompt.

If any solution for that, please share it with me

Comment: did u try restarting your adb using kill-server and start-server?

Comment: may be your adb server is down. try running following commands:

1) adb kill-server
2) adb start-server
3) adb devices

Comment: ya i do it,still now i got same result,but display only in emulator...

Comment: its not workigs,only show list of emulator run in pc

Comment: hi mudit ,run above commands, no response for me;;; any other way to rectify this problem

Comment: May be you should enable ADB debug on device?

Comment: how to enable adb debug on device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable usb debugging on your device. Check this post also [Problem when connecting my device to PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510471/problem-when-connecting-my-device-to-pc/7511988#7511988) ,if enabling USB debugging doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As mihail wrote - you need to enable usb debugging. Unplug the usb cable, go to Settings ->  Manage Applications -> Usb debugging -> turn in on and re-plug the cable. Device should be recognized as development one and drivers will be installed(win7 should find them automatically)