# Android device not seen by ADB but accessible from Windows XP

Tags: android, windows

I just bought a new Nexus 7 tablet and I am trying to put my first Java application on it. However, I am stuck at a very basic point: ADB does not see my device. When I check on my working station, Windows perfectly detects the tablet, I switched the USB port and every one make appear the device but ADB still cannot see it. I rebooted and it is still not working. Any idea about this?

***Update***

There was actually two problems. First, I had not activated the **USB debugging** mode. This was the reason why I could use the tablet from the working station (as a simple multimedia player) even though the correct USB driver was not installed.

Second, the driver was not detected by Windows XP (even we I specified the correct repository to search for it). The problem was solved by following the procedure described by [adamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342605/adamp)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Thomas K points out, you need to install the ADB driver for the device from the SDK manager. Also confirm that USB debugging is enabled on the device as mihail noted.

The basic ADB driver provided with the SDK is generic and can work with any Android device. Simply add the appropriate lines to the `android_winusb.inf` file under `extras/google/usb_driver` to make Windows recognize the device hardware IDs during driver installation. Add the lines under the x86 section for 32 bit Windows or amd64 section for 64 bit Windows.

For the Nexus 7, the configuration you'll need is:

```
;Nexus7
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_01
```

The significant sections there are VID_XXXX and PID_YYYY on both lines. If you have another Android device you would like to add, start by duplicating the lines above in the correct section of the file. You'll need to replace the hardware IDs with the correct IDs for your device.

Open Device Manager, locate the Android device without an ADB driver installed, right click it, and choose Properties. Under the Details tab, select Hardware IDs from the dropdown list. You'll see a line that looks something like `USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_01`. Copy the VID_XXXX section and PID_YYYY section into the two lines you added in the .inf file above. Save the file, then update the driver for the device and use the driver from the directory where the .inf you just saved is.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem, I would never have found that without your help!

Comment: Now I know what I should have added to my post ^^.  ++

Comment: I was having a similar problem and this didn't solve it for me (using the Nexus Toolkit from XDA - this was already set up). In the end I had to delete the Google drivers (yes the actual dll files - I had both version 6 and version 7 from previous SDK installs), as they were taking precedence over these settings.

Comment: Not working for Gogen TA7300. After update of inf file the device is installed as Android Composite ADB Interface (Section Android Phone). Strange is that PID is 0000 (REV2207). Any advice how to get this working? Thanks

Comment: Very, very helpful! Thank you!  My Nexus 7 needed PID of D002, so it's very important to follow the last paragraph about the Device Manager.

Answer (score 4):

U need the appropriate ADB Driver (btw: ADB = "Android debug bridge")

See:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
[ADB dosn't recognize my Galaxy Nexus - Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801829/adb-dosnt-recognize-my-galaxy-nexus-win7)

Download:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW

(Don't dorget to enable debugging on your device under Settings> Applications> Development> USB-debugging )

Also nice to know:

> Note: If you're developing on Mac OS X or Linux, then you do not need
>   to install a USB driver. To start developing with your device, also
>   read Using Hardware Devices.

If you already did all above, this may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563780/1351347

Answer (score 3):

1. do you mean ADB?
2. Have you enabled USB Debugging on your device **Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging**
3. Have you installed correct usb driver for the adb interface? If not check [Problem when connecting my device to PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510471/problem-when-connecting-my-device-to-pc/7511988#7511988) for more information

Comment: 1 - yes, I corrected that
2 - No, I had enabled debuging, but not that option. Thank you, I am trying that right now.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding the entry in adb_usb.ini for my device. Which turned out to be embedded in the hardware id

So - My hardware id was USB\VID_**1C9E**&PID_9E18&MI_01

and I added

0x1c9e

to the adb_usb.ini file under c:\users[user name].android

full file contents -

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.

0x1c9e
```

Answer (score 0):

Still Having Problems?

After turning on USB debugging on my device and properly setting up the drivers for windows to recognize the device.  I still wasn't able to get ADB to recognize my Insignia Flex 8 tablet.  Here's what I had to do:
Create (if it doesn't already exist) - c:\documents and settings\your-user-name.android\adb_usb.ini
Add a line with the VID ID value in hexadecimal form:
  my id value (ascertained from ...device manager; right click android composite adb interface; properties; details) is: USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&MI_00\9&1670302B&0&0000

so the line i added to adb_usb.ini was:
0x2207

save the file and restart eclipse (and/or DDMS; left inverted triangle; reset adb).

after doing this, my NS-14T002 device as available for debugging my application.

Update-> strange, I didn't see the above (same solution) when I initially wrote this (not sure how this wasn't visible...)