# Android 2.3.6 isn't recognized

Tags: android, adb

I have an application that I want to test on real device, and I have a Samsung Galaxy Mini which runs on android 2.3.6, but since the only available SDK for that is 2.3.3, I have selected that as a target build. When I plugin in USB ,windows does recognize it but eclipse does not, it won't install app on the device nor show it when the emulator is also running. Is it some kind of bug or what?

This is the manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidhive"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ng_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Init"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidhive.HOME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CurentNews"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_curent_news" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidhive.CURENTNEWS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".News"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_news" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidhive.NEWS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging?

Comment: yea ,and i set to include apps that are not part of Market Service

Comment: Have you installed the required drivers?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in device driver.
Can you please

1. Check output of "adb devices" command in console?
2. If nothing - check whick driver is installed for the device, and if necessary - manually install AndroidPhone -> ADB Debug Interface (In a list of system drivers)
3. Also check if "Allow USB debugging" is on in phone's Developer Settings.

PS: If no driver is found in the system - use SDK Manager to download GoogleUSB Driver, it will appear in "Extras" folder in Android SDK.

Good luck

Comment: Google USB drivers are only meant for nexus devices. For all other devices you should use the drivers provided by the manufacturer

Comment: That is not 100% right, I'd used it a lot along many HTC devices and it works perfectly. Seems from some SDK they'd provided a general driver for all "ADB Interface" devices. But you are right, some years ago I had troubles with this driver, but not now.

Comment: @Raghav Sood: ADB drivers are the same regardless of device. You only need drivers from the manufacturer if you want the extra features they bundle. See this answer for how you can configure the driver for any device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582410/android-device-not-seen-by-adb-but-accessible-from-windows-xp/11582776#11582776