# HTC windows 7 drivers

Tags: android, windows-7, adb, driver, htc-android

I have an HTC One V device, I am running some commands via ADB and using the drive mode to access from pc.

I know that HTC Sync installs the drivers, and it works completely fine. However I would like to install just the drivers without HTC sync application itself.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Wrong forum. Try here http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You usually get the option as you run the installer. It should install drivers, then move on to HTC synch, which you can then just cancel. Alternatively you should be able to remove the application of 'HTC Synch' and still have the drivers installed. (Tested this in windows 7, but on an older HTC with an older version of synch)

Comment: @Simon I will check that site as well.

Comment: @RossC that can be a good option if i cannot find something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to install the android usb driver and add the hardware ids of your phone in the `android_winusb.inf` file - check this [Problem when connecting my device to PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510471/problem-when-connecting-my-device-to-pc/7511988#7511988) .This should be enough for sending commands from adb. I also use HTC phone and I've never installed any drivers or sync software and this work just fine for me.

Comment: Are the hardware ids unique for each phone? because if yes, then this will not work in my case cause i am going to use different phones later on.

Comment: each model has its own ids. Every HTC One V will work with the ids of your, for any other device model you should add these ids to the android_winusb.inf file. Not really hard work at all.

Comment: @user1632765 , did you find out the ID's for the One V? I couldn't and have the same problem..

Comment: to find the Hardware Ids you will need to have installed the android usb driver. Then, Start->Run-> 'mmc devmgmt.msc'. Click on Device Manager on the left pane, then on the right pane you should see Android Device (your phone must be connected to the computer with usb debugging enabled). Open properties for 'Android Composite ADB Interface', then in the details tab choose 'Hardware Ids' from the dropdown.